# Why data doesn't get to the server?

Tags: php, html

I wanted to UPDATE these details from few tables, can i know how can i do it? it seems not appearing.

```
<body>
    <form class="" action="view_update_emp.php" method="post">
        <label>Employee Number</label><br>
        <b><?php echo $row['emp_num']; ?><br></b>
        <label>First Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter first name" value="<?php echo $row['first_name']; ?>"><br>
        <label>Last Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter last name" value="<?php echo $row['last_name']; ?>"><br>
        <label>Date of Birth</label><br>
        <b> <?php echo $row['birth_date']; ?></b><br><br>
        <label>Date assigned for the job position</label><br>
        <b><?php echo $row['date_assign']; ?></b><br>
        <label>Salary</label><br>
        <input type="number" name="emp_salary" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Salary" value="<?php echo $row['emp_salary']; ?>"><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update" value="Update Data">Update</button><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="cancel" value="Cancel Data">Cancel</button><br>
    </form>

</body>
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'amaz');

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $query = "UPDATE `employee`  SET first_name='$_POST[first_name]',last_name='$_POST[last_name]' WHERE employee.first_name='$_POST[id]'";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if ($query_run) {
        echo "sucess";
    }
} else if (isset($_POST['cancel'])) {
    echo "fail";
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: You need to look up how to use a hidden `<input type="hidden" ...` to allow you to access the id

Comment: Clearly `first_name` isn't going to equal an ID value....that just doesn't make any sense. And your form doesn't even contain an ID value to submit...see RiggsFolly's comment above.

Comment: Your actual question is unclear though...which other tables do you need to update, other than the one shown in your code? And what problem are you having with doing that, exactly?

Comment: As an aside, `if (isset($_POST['cancel'])) {
    echo "fail";` makes no logical sense. The user cancelling something isn't a system failure.

Comment: That's way too much for one question. It should be closed. You have to figure out the required SQL first, without any PHP or html. Then learn how to execute SQL from PHP. And only then add some HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace this

```
<label>Employee Number</label><br>
<b><?php echo $row['emp_num']; ?><br></b>
```

With a hidden fields to hold the key you need later in a way that you can access it when you need to

```
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['emp_num']; ?>" name="id">
```

The user will not see this, but it will allow `$_POST[id]` to hold the value of the `emp_num` when you get back to the PHP code after submission

You would also need to change the update query

```
WHERE employee.first_name='$_POST[id]'
```

To

```
WHERE employee.emp_num='$_POST[id]'
```